# Google Chrome -where the downloaded js files form a website are stored in our local machine

Tags: google-chrome

When browsing an website, javascript files will be loaded into our local machine by browser.
Im curious to find out where the files are stored in our local machine.
(Curios after I seen the list of js files (in directory structure, as like my workspace) in the 'Sources' panel - Google Chrome web inspector)

I can say that it will be in Temp files or Chrome/Firefox App data, but can anybody tell me where exactly the files are saved?

Comment: This may help: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/keN3Njx6gtM

Answer (score 2):

The location varys from browser to browser and is different on most operating systems. You have to be more specific about what browser.

Google chrome for example uses the following path to store temporary data:

- Windows Vista: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
- Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings[USERNAME]\Local
  Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\
- Windows 7/8: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
  Data\Default\Cache
- Mac OS X: /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/

Comment: Hi, Im using Chrome,
Windows 7/8: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

I dont see js files in the cache folder. Lot of flat files. Chrome saves cache like this in a custom way? We can't see the files directly?